# Modeline for indentation with tabs in Emacs

Tags: emacs, tabs, indentation

I have a project that relies in modelines to specify that tabs should be used.

The first line of the file is the C++ comment `/* -*- indent-tabs-mode: t; -*- */`

However, it seems that emacs ignores this.
If I type `int f() {[enter][tab]return 0;[enter]}`, I only get spaces:

```
int f() {
  return 0;
}
```

How should the modeline look like so that [tab] produces an actual tab.

I don't want to impose the width of a tab/indentation but I will if I have to for this to work.

**EDIT**: To summarize,

1. **How do I make [tab] simply add one (or more) tab ('\t') to the document and never spaces?**
2. An option similar to `tab-width` that only changes the way things are displayed rather than affecting the behavior just described above.

Comment: One tab character will be used for each multiple of `tab-width`.  If the indentation column is not an exact multiple of `tab-width`, spaces must be used to make up the difference.

Comment: @phils: Please consider posting your comment as an answer. (It's the answer, IMO.)

Comment: There will undoubtedly be a sensible duplicate question, but I didn't have time to figure out the best one.

Comment: @phils, yes, I experimentally found that. I guess the question is, how do I make [tab] simply add one (or more) tab ('\t') to the document and never spaces. And separately, a version of `tab-width` that _only_ changes the way things are displayed rather than affecting the behavior just described.

Comment: `tab-width` itself does *only* change the way things are displayed -- but the indentation code pays attention to its value when deciding which characters to indent with if you have `indent-tabs-mode` set, because it *has* to do so.  You'll want to make sure that indentation config is aligned with `tab-width` config.  As you're writing C++ have a read of `C-h i g (ccmode)Customizing Indentation`

Comment: @phils, that is the confusing part: `tab-width` is not a "hidden" value. As you said "indentation pays attention to its value...", that means that it is not just a display variable. Perhaps what I need is a modeline that uses the value of `tab-width` to set other variables. The other problem is that I don't want to force the _displayed_ width of a pure tab for others (other emacs users). Perhahs I should mention that not all the developers are using emacs. And is emacs the one that it playing worstly with the others for this reason.

Comment: Emacs indents to specific *columns*.  If `indent-tabs-mode` is nil then it will use 1 space per column (and you *need* everyone to use the same indentation size).  If `indent-tabs-mode` is non-nil then it will still indent by columns, but every multiple of `tab-width` will become a tab character.  If you are using a language where indentation is always stepping up or down by the same fixed number of columns then all you need to do is make the indentation step and the tab width value the same number -- then each indent will be a tab.

Comment: Note that in the latter case you are free to choose the size of indent step for your own config, so long as you also set the tab-width to the same number.  The end result will be one tab per step, and you can share the file with someone who has chosen a different size (but likewise aligned that with their tab-width) and things Just Work, because it's one tab character per step for everyone, even though the indentation looks larger or smaller.

Comment: In short, Emacs calculates the correct column to indent something to (based on your indentation config), and then uses tabs and/or spaces as appropriate to get to that column.  Note that many languages do not use fixed steps for indentation (indentation might be to *any* column), and so Emacs would be unable to indent those languages correctly if it was not allowed to use spaces when `indent-tabs-mode` was enabled.